# batch: adding %'s to a value to declare another variable

Tags: batch-file

I have a file called "**VAR.bat**" that sets variables:

```
SET VARa=C:\Program Files
SET VARb=C:\Program Files (x86)
set VARc=C:\ProgramData
```

I have a file another called "**SET.set**" that contains just variable names:

```
VARa
VARb
VARc
```

I would like to call upon the set from a routine like this:

```
 for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('type "SET.set"') do (
    SET CONSA=%%~a
    SET CONSN=%%^%%a%%
    CALL :CREATEVAR
    )
    :CREATEVAR
    if exist "%CONSN%" CALL :%CONSA%_detect
    exit /b

:VARa_detect
echo "%CONSN%"
exit /b

:VARb_detect
echo "%CONSN%"
exit /b

:VARc_detect
echo "%CONSN%"
exit /b
```

Using the **^** to escape and add a **%** to a value isn't working because the command processor interprets the value as "**%VARa%**" and not "**C:\Program Files**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the delayed expansion here.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('type "SET.set"') do (
    SET CONSA=%%~a
    SET CONSN=!%%~a!
    CALL :CREATEVAR
)
```

Or at the same line you could use an extra expaqnsion by `CALL`

```
...
call set CONSN=%%%%~a%%
```